# Scrapy LinkExtractor not working

Tags: scrapy

Having trouble with my Scrapy crawler following links. Below is my code. I want it to essentially go to YouTube pages, pull the twitter links, and then call parse_page3 and pull in information but right now, only the parse_page2 extraction part is working.

Thanks!
Eric

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
# from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from tutorial.items import YTItem

class YTSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "youtube"
    allowed_domains = ["youtube.com","twitter.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.youtube.com/jackcontemusic/about",
        "https://www.youtube.com/user/natalydawn/about"
    ]

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('twitter.com',)), callback='parse_twitter'),]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = YTItem()
        item['main_url'] = response.url
        request = scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_page2)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['joindate'] = response.selector.xpath('normalize-space(//li[contains(text(),"Joined")]/text())').extract()
        item['subscribers'] = response.selector.xpath('//li[@class="about-stat " and contains(.,"subscribers")]/node()/node()').extract()
        item['views'] = response.selector.xpath('//li[@class="about-stat " and contains(.,"views")]/node()/node()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="cmt_iframe_holder"]/@data-href').extract()
        item['fb'] = response.selector.xpath('(//li[@class="channel-links-item"]/a[@title="Facebook"]/@href)[1]').extract()
        item['twitter'] = response.selector.xpath('(//li[@class="channel-links-item"]/a[@title="Twitter"]/@href)[1]').extract()
        item['googleplus'] = response.selector.xpath('(//li[@class="channel-links-item"]/a[@title="Google+"]/@href)[1]').extract()
        item['itunes'] = response.selector.xpath('(//li[@class="channel-links-item"]/a[@title="iTunes"]/@href)[1]').extract()
        item['instagram'] = response.selector.xpath('(//li[@class="channel-links-item"]/a[@title="Instagram"]/@href)[1]').extract()
        return item

    def parse_twitter(self, response):
        item = YTItem()
        item['twitter_url'] = response.url
        request = scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_twitter)
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['tweets'] = response.selector.xpath('(//span[@class="ProfileNav-value"])[1]').extract()
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Rule`s and `LinkExtractor`s, you need to use [`CrawlSpider` class](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider).

Replace:

```
class YTSpider(scrapy.Spider):
```

with:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider

class YTSpider(CrawlSpider):
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe. Do I need to change what I enter in terminal to execute it? scrapy crawl youtube -o items.json is what I'm currently using it. Still having trouble getting it to work